# How to view the latest logs on an Amazon S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

How to view the latest logs when there are too many logs in an Amazon S3 bucket?

Note: Tried with prefix, but couldn't fetch the required current year logs.

Comment: Which type of log?

Comment: CloudFront access log.

Comment: What do you mean by "too many logs"?

Answer (score 0):

The [log format](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/AccessLogs.html#AccessLogsFileNaming) is below

```
<optional prefix>/<distribution ID>.YYYY-MM-DD-HH.unique-ID.gz
```

So you would need to include in the prefix the distribution id, followed by the date time.

If you're just trying to access the most current logs, might I suggest you take a look at [Athena to query the logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/cloudfront-logs.html) as it will likely be far easier to query for the information you are trying to retrieve.

Comment: Tried Athena to fetch a single day log with query: SELECT * FROM accesslogs_xxxx where date like '%2020-05-24%' , but got SYNTAX_ERROR: line 1:36: Left side of LIKE expression must evaluate to a varchar (actual: date).

Comment: Try running where CAST(date AS DATE) = '2020-05-24'

Comment: Got SYNTAX_ERROR: line 1:55: '=' cannot be applied to date, varchar(10)

Comment: Oops wrong way round, should be date = CAST('2020-05-24' as date)